# Filling space between floating elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have container div (gray box) with floating elements inside: [image]

Bars are floating to the left and button if floating to the right. Now I want textbox to fill the empty space between the bars and the button.

**Please note that bars count may vary during typind so textbox should be able to resize accordingly.** So solutions with static widths (even if they are expressed in %) will not work.

How can I do it?

**EDIT:**

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="dp-container">
    <ol id="tag-list">
        <li dp-item class="dp-bar-table">sales</li>
        <li dp-item class="dp-bar-field">cost</li>
    </ol>

    <input id="dp-input-str" type="text">
    <input type="button" value="GO" style="float: right;">
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ol {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li[dp-item] {
    background-color: #e0ffff;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 2px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#FEFEFE), to(#EBEBEB));
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.dp-bar-table {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dp-bar-field {
    color: blue;
}

#dp-input-str {
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: auto;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 12pt;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 25px;
    box-shadow: none;

#dp-container {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 90%;
}

#dp-find-str {
    color: gray;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Comment: if we will give the static width so how it can be resize... its not possible with static fix width we will have to give atleast % than we will be able to resize the textbox

Comment: plz post your code somewhere to use it and fix it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be that's you want check this http://jsfiddle.net/bYmM4/7/ . Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
 <input type="button" value="test" />
 <input type="button" value="test" />
    <input type="button" value="Go" class="go"/>
    <div class="textbox">
     <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main{position:relative; border:#333 1px solid}
input[type="button"]{width:8%; float:left;}
.textbox{
    background-color:grey;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.textbox input{
    width:100%;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
input.go{float:right}
```

Comment: Looks like what I need. Need some investigation to accept it.