# CSS - floating LIs - and filling space in between

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists, fill

I have an unordered list which I have all items par the last one floated left - and the last one floated right. Like the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/AkwnJ/.

What I'd like to do, on LI #9 (coloured grey) is for that to fill the space between the 8th item and the 10th item. But I do not know how to do this. Could someone inform me how. I have been attempting to follow this example: http://jsfiddle.net/bYmM4/7/ which was taken from here: [Filling space between floating elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257517/filling-space-between-floating-elements). However, the example uses DIVs whereas I'm using a UL - so ever so slightly different. But surely the same principles applies?

Hopefully someone here knows which would be a huge benefit?

To save you having to go to jsFiddle, my HTML and CSS is as follows:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li class="fill"><div>9</div></li>
    <li class="end">10</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    border: black 1px solid;
}

li.end {
    float: right;
}

li.fill {
    overflow: hidden;
}

li.fill div {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Thanks!

**Edit**: removed a bit of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last element should be second to last, right before de wide element. Also the wide element needs display: block and width: auto.

http://jsfiddle.net/HkChk/

```
li.fill {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Perfect - just what I'm looking for! This in combination with the second answer fulfills all my requirements! I wish I could chose both as the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of floating elements use a CSS table like this:

```
ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

li:nth-last-child(2) {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 30px;
}
```

As a note: `:nth-last-child(2)` will style the next to last element. Using this you can get rid of adding an extra class to this specific element. This doesn't work in IE8 but you can use [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com) to make it work there too. In the end you can of course use a class instead, like in your question.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/VpmAP/)

Comment: This answer is awesome - I like the use of the nth-last-child selector which will save a huge amount of hassle having to find my second-to-last item every time :).